# Discrete Math Formula Equivalence Proof

Tags: logic

How can I prove that the following two statements are equivalent, using Formula Equivalence laws?

```
f(x) and (g(x) and h(x)) 
(f(x) and g(x)) and (f(x) and h(x))
```

I know that by associativity, `f(x) and (g(x) and h(x))` is equal to `(f(x) and g(x)) and h(x)`. I am also thinking to use distributive laws to prove this, but they  state that `A ∪ (B ∩ C) = (A ∪ B) ∩ (A ∪ C)` or `A ∩ (B ∪ C) = (A ∩ B) ∪ (A ∩ C)` (the law uses a union and intersection, rather than two intersections).

Any help to get me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have two intersections ("and's") and no unions which are expressed with "or". So the equivalence is actually straightforward

Comment: I am looking at a list of set identities, and I do not see anything that can help me prove this. What identify should I be looking to use?

Comment: You can use the fact that $f\wedge f = f$ (I don't know the name for this property) as well as the commutative property that $f\wedge g = g\wedge f$.

Comment: @JMoravitz The fact $f\land f=f$ is called *idempotent law*.

Comment: @JMoravitz Can you prove it using *just* commutativity and idempotence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For X(x), I just write X.

Axiom 1: ∧(X, Y)=∧(Y, X). (commutativity)

Axiom 2: ∧(X, ∧(Y, Z))=∧(∧(X, Y), Z). (associativity)

Axiom 3: ∧(X, X)=X.  (idempotence).

A set with a binary operation "∧" with the above axioms as axioms or theorems forms an idempotent commutative semigroup.  I'll drop parentheses in the following:

1. ∧F∧GH=∧F∧GH (axiom of "x=x" for equality).
2. ∧F∧GH=∧∧FF∧GH idempotence on 1.
3. ∧F∧GH=∧F∧F∧GH associativity on 2.
4. ∧F∧GH=∧F∧∧FGH associativity on 3.
5. ∧F∧GH=∧F∧∧GFH commutativity on 4.
6. ∧F∧GH=∧F∧G∧FH associativity on 5.
7. ∧F∧GH=∧∧FG∧FH associativity on 6.

Therefore, ∧ distributes over itself.  Since $\lor$ satisfies commutation and association and idempotence also, $\lor$ distributes over itself.